# Laravel Gulp including a file within .pipe

Tags: gulp, laravel-5

How can I include a file within the pipe so that they include and min into the app.min.js file?

```
jsSrc = 'resources/temp/*.js';//Your js source directory
jsDest = 'public/admin/js/';//Your js destination directory

// Make Minify JS

gulp.task('scripts', function(){
    return gulp.src(jsSrc)
           .pipe(concat('app.js'))
           .pipe(gulp.dest(jsDest))
           .pipe(rename('app.min.js'))
           .pipe(uglify())
           .pipe(gulp.dest(jsDest))
           .pipe(livereload());

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to include the file in both  `app.js` and `app.min.js` just add it to your `jsSrc` variable:

```
var jsSrc = [
  'resources/temp/*.js',
  'path/to/additional/file.js'
];
```

If you want to include it **only** in `app.min.js`, use the [`gulp-add-src`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-add-src) plugin:

```
var addsrc = require('gulp-add-src');

gulp.task('scripts', function(){
  return gulp.src(jsSrc)
    .pipe(concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(jsDest))
    .pipe(addsrc.append('path/to/additional/file.js'))
    .pipe(concat('app.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(jsDest))
    .pipe(livereload());
});
```

This adds the file to the end of `app.min.js`. If you want to add it to the beginning use `addsrc.prepend()` instead.